# Filter multiple objects from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to filter an array of objects where the filter is another array (of integers) which are values of properties of the first array. I've managed to make it work but I'm not sure if it's the best way. Since I'm a beginner in javascript, I'd appreciate any suggestions/improvements.

The **items.json** file contains an object with an array of objects. I want to filter all the objects (within that array) that have an `id` equal to the "ids" on the **itemsids** array.

**code:**

```
const itemsall = require('./items.json');

let itemsids = [1, 403, 3];

let filtereditems = [];

itemsids.forEach(id => {
  itemsall.items.forEach(item => {
    if (id === item.id) {
      filtereditems.push(item);
    }
  });
});
```

**items.json (a small part of it)**

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Egg",
            "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/egg.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Pokeball",
            "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/20pokeballs.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Greatball",
            "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/greatball.png"
        }
   ]
}
```

**output: (expected)**

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Egg",
        "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/egg.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 403,
        "name": "Cool Incense",
        "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/incense.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Ultraball",
        "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/ultraball.png"
    }
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `indexOf()` to return filtered array.

```js
var data = {
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Egg",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/egg.png"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Pokeball",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/20pokeballs.png"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Greatball",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/items/greatball.png"
  }]
}
let itemsids = [1, 403, 3];

var result = data.items.filter(function(e) {
  return itemsids.indexOf(e.id) != -1
})

console.log(result)
```

With ES6/ES7 you can use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like this.

```
var result = data.items.filter((e) => itemsids.includes(e.id));
```

Comment: Thanks ! I used the 2nd method (ES6/7) since its running server-side. Much more simple and clean.